# inno setup create box to install additional programs

Tags: inno-setup

I'm a newbie to inno setup and I'm trying to create my setup for the first time.
I need to add some components to my setup

my scenario:

1. choose additional components with boxes
2. copy necessary files to {pf}\myapp
3. launch setup of additional components selected before

   I don't find an easy solution for point 3.

any suggestions?

thanks to all

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and show us what you have tried yourself sofar

Comment: It is possible to achieve this with Inno Setup but rather check some tutorials and ask specific question when something is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

solved with TASKS .

```
[Files]
```

Source: "..\input\MRV\scripts\ConfigFile_FIRMA_STAMPA.ini"; DestDir: "{app}\Config\"; DestName: "ConfigFile.ini"; Flags: ignoreversion; Tasks: FCS
Source: "..\input\MRV\scripts\ConfigFile_FIRMA_NOSTAMPA.ini"; DestDir: "{app}\Config\"; DestName: "ConfigFile.ini"; Flags: ignoreversion; Tasks: FSS
Source: "..\input\MRV\scripts\ConfigFile_NOFIRMA_STAMPA.ini"; DestDir: "{app}\Config\"; DestName: "ConfigFile.ini"; Flags: ignoreversion; Tasks: NFCS
Source: "..\input\MRV\scripts\ConfigFile_NOFIRMA_NOSTAMPA.ini"; DestDir: "{app}\Config\"; DestName: "ConfigFile.ini"; Flags: ignoreversion; Tasks: NFSS

[Tasks]
Name: "FCS"; Description: "Description1"; GroupDescription: "Parametri Extra"; Flags: unchecked exclusive
Name: "FSS"; Description: "Description2"; GroupDescription: "Parametri Extra"; Flags: unchecked exclusive
Name: "NFCS"; Description: "Description3"; GroupDescription: "Parametri Extra"; Flags: unchecked exclusive
Name: "NFSS"; Description: "Description4"; GroupDescription: "Parametri Extra"; Flags: unchecked exclusive

thanks for help